# jQuery title attribute to textbox

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery.  I have a list of links in my app.  I want to be able to take the title attribute of any of the links and put it in a text box on a page when the link is clicked.  This is what I've got so far but it doesn't work:

```
 <p><a href="#" title="text I want to get">Link 1</a></p>
 <p><a href="#" title="more text I want to get">Link 2</a></p>
 <p><input id="myTextBox" type="text">​</p>

$("a").attr("title").click(function () {
$('#myTextBox').attr($(this).attr());
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely read the `attr` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/. `.attr('title')` returns a **string**. Strings don't have a `.click` method. Don't just put stuff together, read the documentation and have a look at the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of the right keywords, but they aren't wired up quite right. The `.attr()` getter isn't chainable, for example.

This gets all links that have a title and adds the click handler to them:

```
$('a[title]').on('click', function(){ 
  $('#myTextBox').val( $(this).attr('title') );
  //                            ^^ this returns a string and passes it to .val()
});
```

When clicked, the textbox's value will be replaced with the link's title attribute's value.

This could be a little more verbose. If you are new, I suggest writing things more like this initially as it makes things much easier to debug. Once you're more comfortable with the jQuery way of doing things, the denser, chained approach will be more natural.

```
$('a[title]').on('click', function(){ 
  var $link = $(this);
  var titleText = $link.attr('title');
  var $textbox = $('#myTextBox');
  $textbox.val(titleText);
});
```

Comment: Since he's new, you should note the lack of a semicolon. I didn't understand that when I was new and it would sure have helped if people had told me about it. Also, +1 for good answer using `on()`.

Comment: @Purmou I'm not entirely sure what you mean about the semicolon. It wasn't intentionally left out in this case. Are you saying it should work either way (it should)?

Comment: No, I mean not having a semicolon after `attr('title')`.

Comment: @Purmou ah, ok. I'll add a note. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even notice that you didn't put it at the end...ironic. But yeah, it would have worked anyways.

Comment: This is awesome - thank you!  I really appreciate the explanation - definitely helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I can somewhat see the logic that led you to produce this, but I strongly recommend reading the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com) and [API Reference](http://api.jquery.com) so that you get a better understanding of what to do.

That said, this should do the trick for you:

```
$('p').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#myTextBox").val( title );
});
```

An explanation so you can get an idea of what's happening here:

Instead of using `click()`, I'm using `on()`, which is delegates events rather than attaching them to specific events. So if it detects a click event on any `p` element, and as long as the target of that element was an `a` element *within* that given `p` element, it'll execute the handler.

Then, we assign the value of the `title` attribute of the clicked link to the variable `title`.

We then just set the `value` attribute of the input to said title variable, and voila.

Good luck!